# How to export hash -d directories to scripts?

Tags: zsh

I like to use hash -d. I want to use the hashed directories in a script.

example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
echo $SHLVL
hash -d 
echo "+++++++"
ls ~dd
```

Running:

```
hash -d dd=/tmp
hash -d 
echo "-----"
./example
```

will print out

```
dd=/tmp
-----
2
+++++
./example: no such user or named directory: ~dd
```

However, functions work just fine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
function example() {
  hash -d
  cd ~dd
}
```

Of course the quick check of `$SHLVL` shows that the script called as a script has a lower shell level. With variables, I can do an `export` to make those variables available. How to do the same thing for `hash -d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
export dd=/foo/bar
```

You don't need to call `hash -d` explicitly. The *z shell* uses a heuristic if it expands `~something` as a named dir (see *Static named directories* in the *zshexpn* manual page) or not. That is the most important part

> They may also be defined if the text
>          after the ~ is the name of a string shell parameter whose value begins with a `/`

Comment: i didn't know that. Thanks it works.